# Select columns with and without group by

Tags: sql

Having Table1

```
id | productname | store   | price  
-----------------------------------  
1  |      name a | store 1 |     4  
2  |      name a | store 2 |     3  
3  |      name b | store 3 |     6  
4  |      name a | store 3 |     4  
5  |      name b | store 1 |     7  
6  |      name a | store 4 |     5  
7  |      name c | store 3 |     2  
8  |      name b | store 6 |     5  
9  |      name c | store 2 |     1
```

I need to get all columns but only the rows with the
lowest price.
Result needed:

```
id | productname | store   | price  
-----------------------------------  
2  |      name a | store 2 |     3  
8  |      name b | store 6 |     5  
9  |      name c | store 2 |     1
```

My best try is:

```
SELECT ProductName, MIN(Price) AS minPrice  
FROM Table1  
GROUP BY ProductName
```

But then I need the `ID` and `STORE` for each row.

Comment: Is `GROUP BY Id, ProductName, Store` what you want?

Comment: What if two rows have same price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select p.* from  Table1 as p inner join 
(SELECT ProductName, MIN(Price) AS minPrice    FROM Table1      GROUP BY ProductName) t 
on p.productname  = t.ProductName and p.price = t.minPrice
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select ID,ProductName,minPrice
from
(
SELECT ProductName, MIN(Price) AS minPrice
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ProductName
) t
join Table1 t1 on t.ProductName = t1.ProductName
```

Comment: This will give duplicates when two prices are the lowest on a product.

Comment: then use distinct or instead of group by over (partition by productname oder by order name) having = 1

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention your SQL dialect, but most DBMSes support Standard SQL's "Windowed Aggregate Functions":

```
select *
from
  ( select t.*,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductName ORDER BY Price) as rnk 
    from table1 as t
  ) as dt
where rnk = 1
```

If multiple stores got the same lowest price all of them will be returned. If you want only a single shop you have to switch to ROW_NUMBER instead of RANK or add column(s) to the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table1` AS `t1`
WHERE (
   SELECT count(*) FROM `Table1` AS `t2` WHERE `t1`.`productName` = `t2`.`productName` AND `t2`.`price` < `t1`.`price`) < 1
```

Check [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24a171/4)

But if you have same products with same minimum price in two stores, you will get both of them in result output

Answer (score 0):

I think this query should do:

```
select min(t.id) id
,      t.productname
,      t.price
from   table1 t
join
( select min(price) min_price
  ,      productname
  from   table1
  group
  by     productname
) v
on     v.productname = t.productname
and    v.price = t.min_price
group
by     t.productname
,      t.price
```

It determines the lowest price per product and fetches every line in the base table (`t`). This avoids duplicates by grouping on the `productname` and selecting the lowest `id`.